# SPOL REST api url not functioning with a SPOL do lib

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using REST with SPOL and I am trying to get a image from a image doc.  The way I would usually do it works fine for me because I am using a relative url to the picture.

**The ways I usually do this**

```
imgUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/ContentCenter/docLib/" + spItems[z].text + "." + spItems[z].fileType + "')/$value";
```

However, I am trying to switch from this because List Id's are better to reference for accuracy.  So I am trying to construct the url I am trying to use.  I am using this however I am not able to get the image.  I just get the item properties, unlike when I use value.

**Not working**

```
"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('docLib')/Items?$filter=ID eq '79'&$value";
```

Answer (score 0):

After using some Fiddler this was the url that worked for me

```
imgUrl = "https://tentant.sharepoint.com/sites/testSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('docLib')/items('79')/File/$value";
```